# what causes this copy pasting bug?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, ms-paint, copy-and-paste

I found this odd and unexpected copy paste behavior using Photoshop CC and windows 7 MS Paint

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FIVXog49k4

Can anyone explain what might be happening here?  Very curious about this.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Why are you copying and pasting from MS Paint into Photoshop?  What are you trying to achieve by doing that? Can't you just open the image in Photoshop, and edit it within Photoshop?

Comment: @BillyKerr - Sometimes, depending on your source, meta data is transferred from the clipboard, too, which can cause speed issues or other unforeseen problems (I've experienced similar myself). By pasting into MS Paint, first, then copying and pasting into Photoshop, the meta data is usually stripped.

Comment: @Paul  - what I'm asking is why the OP is even using MS Paint.  Why would anyone need to copy and paste from MS Paint into Photoshop?  MS Paint is not needed for any part of any workflow with Photoshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be the color profile used by Photoshop, verify that you're not using a color profile for your document.

Comment: Hello Hassan ALAMI, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!

Comment: thank you @Vincent for your observation, i just edited my contribution